# How to rewrite For-loop and If-statement with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, if-statement, java-stream

*My code*:

```
final List<Employee> empList= getEmployeeList();
String empid = "1234";
Employee selectedEmp = new Employee();

for (Employee e1: empList) {
    if (empid .equals(e1.getEmpid()))
        selectedEmp = e1;
    }
}
```

Now I want to rewrite the above code in Java 8.

I've tried the following, but without success. I can't figure out translate the `if`-statement:

```
empList.stream()
    .foreach( <how to apply if condition here>)
```

Comment: empList.stream().foreach( <here how to check above if condition>)

Answer (score 8):

`forEach()` isn't the appropriate tool here.

Firstly there's a method `Iterable.forEach()` which you can invoke directly on a list without creating a stream, secondly `Stream.forEach()` is **not** encouraged to be used in such a way by the [Stream API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects), it should be used with care in cases when you have no other tools suitable for the task.

Instead, you can use combination [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) + [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()), which produces result of type Optional.

To provide a default value for the case when employee wasn't found (*like in your code a dummy* `Employee` *object created via no-args constructor*) you can use [`Optional.orElseGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)) which expects a `Supplier` that would be applied only when needed (*when optional is empty*).

```
public Employee findEmployee(String empid) {
    
    return getEmployeeList().stream()
        .filter(e -> empid.equals(e.getEmpid()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(Employee::new);
}
```

<sup>I strongly recommend you to get familiar with these tutorials on [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) and [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)</sup>